# How can I add a contribution to a project on Sourceforge on the careers page without having a sf.net user?

Tags: feature-request, jobs

I contributed code to a project that I'd like to link to from my career entry but I didn't setup a user at the time so I'm not directly affiliated with the project.  I am obviously in the credits and in the change log, just not with a proper user.  I'm guessing this sort of problem may apply to others with some of the other online repositories too?

It would be handy to be able to point to that project and explain my (tiny) contribution to it.

Comment: I just noticed the catch all bit at the end where I've stuck the info for now, but it would be a lot nicer if I could add that info along side the rest of the open source projects I've worked on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the case of SourceForge, we don't actually verify the user, so you can put in the user name of the owner of that project, which will then allow you to add the project to your profile. Just be sure to explain your role so there is no confusion to viewers of your profile.

(We handle SourceForge on the "honor system" since they don't have authentication on their API.)

Comment: I had considered doing that but I wasn't sure what would happen, I didn't want to accidentally appear to have stolen credit for work I didn't do ;)  I'll give it a go.